# Steam fonts are very small on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: fonts, steam, hdpi

My screen resolution is 2560x1440 and I am using fractional scaling at 125%.

Steam fonts are unreadable (see the screenshot and compare with the size of the Chrome icon).

[image]

Comment: Mine is 5120x1440 with the same issue, and the answers here helped.

Comment: This is clearly a bug. The text is unreadible even if one puts one face against the screen.

Comment: Or if all else fails, you could run steam on bottles and change the scaling through it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you start Steam from a terminal with the command `GDK_SCALE=2 steam` it seems to work.

I found the answer on [a Manjaro help page](https://forum.manjaro.org/t/scaling-steam-where-to-add-gdk-scale-2/39545/6).

Comment: it's too big now :)

Comment: I tried both 'usr/share/applications/steam.desktop and 'usr/lib/steam/bin_steam.sh' files, but none of them worked, the only one that worked for me is run 'GDK_SCALE=2 steam' in the terminal. But it's a bit annoying that every time I launch steam, I have to do it manually. I appreciate it if you have any other solutions for this issue.
I am using ubuntu 22.04, and my resolution is 2880 x 1800.

Comment: @daGo: you can set a fractional value, mine is perfect with `GDK_SCALE=1.25`

Answer (score 16):

If you want to start `steam` with scaled UI from launchpad, you can set `GDK_SCALE=2` (as mentioned in the accepted solution) in `steam.desktop` file (in my case it is located in `/usr/share/applications`).

First, open the file in your favourite text editor (e.g. `gedit`). You might need superuser privileges:

```
gedit /usr/share/applications/steam.desktop
```

Then change the `Exec` entry value to:

```
Exec=sh -c 'GDK_SCALE=2 /usr/games/steam %U'
```

*Note: your `steam` path can be different to mine (`/usr/games/steam`). Just use the path from your `Exec` entry.*

Comment: You could go `Exec=env GDK_SCALE=2 /usr/games/steam U%`. No need for nesting in a shell then.

Answer (score 11):

Find the `bin_steam.sh`:

```
$ which steam
// >> /usr/bin/steam
$ ls -la /usr/bin/steam
// >> lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 25 Jul 29  2020 /usr/bin/steam -> ../lib/steam/bin_steam.sh
$ ls -la /usr/lib/steam/bin_steam.sh
// >> -rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 5946 Jun 21 14:26 /usr/lib/steam/bin_steam.sh
```

Edit `bin_steam.sh`:

```
$ sudo gedit /usr/lib/steam/bin_steam.sh
```

Add at the beginning `export GDK_SCALE=2`:

[File changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XR8kH.png)

Run Steam as usual and see the changes ;)

Comment: It's not a good idea to edit system or package files. Changes will gone when the package is upgraded. In this case, it's better to add that code in `~/.bashrc` for example.

Comment: Even the comments above suggest to edit the file /usr/share/applications/steam.desktop that is, at least in my case, a symbol link to /usr/lib/steam/steam.desktop that technically leads to changes of the same system or package files.

Comment: For I just used which steam to find my directory and then edited the file "steam" in nano to add the line: export GDK_SCALE=2

Answer (score 2):

For anyone stumbling into this in the future.
If you find the default UI too small and `GDK_SCALE=2` too big, you can apply a zoom to the steam UI instead for 150%, 125% etc.
Here's how for Ubuntu based distros for example: 
(make sure your directories are the same)

```
mkdir -p ~/.steam/steam/skins/steamzoom/resource/styles
cp ~/.steam/steam/resource/styles/steam.styles ~/.steam/steam/skins/steamzoom/resource/styles/steam.styles
echo ":root { zoom: 1.5; }" > ~/.steam/steam/skins/steamzoom/resource/webkit.css
```

You can later apply the last command again to change the zoom size to your preference.
 I personally use 1.25 (125%).
Afterwards go to your Steam Settings -> Interface -> select the new "steamzoom" skin you just created and apply it.

This can also be applied to existing steam skins, for example Adwaita skin you'd only need to

```
echo ":root { zoom: 1.25; }" > ~/.steam/steam/skins/Adwaita/resource/webkit.css
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Steam and Spotify. Changed the fractional scaling back to 100% from 125% and the fonts went back to being readable.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but then I would lose a lot of screen estate :)

Answer (score 0):

Start steam client adding parameters `-w 1368 -h 768` or whatever size you want, always smaller than your monitor resolution. The smaller value, the bigger overall size of steam client, including fonts.

You may add parameters to your Windows shortcut, it works in Linux shortcuts too.